# How to successfully transmit a message over the internet with python sockets?

Tags: python, sockets, networking, python-sockets

I know that to connect to a socket over the internet you have to enable port-forwarding in your router. However, I wonder how instant messengers e.g Whatsapp work without port-forwarding?. I was trying to connect to another device but failed  I set my host as 0.0.0.0 and port to 1803 and it works perfectly over LAN but not over the internet.

Help please?

Edit: My code:

```
import socket,sys

server_socket = socket.socket()
host = socket.gethostname()
port = 1803
server_socket.bind((host, port))
server_socket.listen(1)


while True:
    client, address = server_socket.accept()
    received_data = client.recv(1024).decode('ascii')
    print(received_data)
    sending_data = input('>').encode('ascii')
    client.send(sending_data)
    server_socket.close()
    break


sys.exit()
```

Comment: As stated, this question may be too broad to answer. It would be helpful if you showed your existing code (for talking to a host on a LAN), and also mention a specific server you're trying to talk to, and what you're hoping to get from it by talking to it.

Comment: added my code now

Comment: This looks like the server side of the code. Are you trying to debug the server-side code or the client-side code?

Comment: I mean, let's say I'll have this server running on another device and I'll be trying to connect to it from my own. But over the internet. I know I can use port forwarding, but instant messengers _do_ use sockets, right? And they work perfectly without messing with my router.

Comment: If you run the server code on a device with a public IP address, then you don't need to do port forwarding. Modern instant messengers relay your messages through a server with a public IP address.